# Using a code generation directly in a flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart

I recently created a project for which i need to do some code generation. The code generation is not gneneral enough to warrant creating a custom package. So I thought of having the generator in my lib folder and having a build.yaml in the app's directory.

If I do that, however, my app does not compile, throwing a `Dart Error: error: import of dart:mirrors is not supported in the current Dart runtime`, when I compile the app. I tried understanding what causes the issue and I found that:

to create the builder, I have to import the code generation libraries (source_gen and build) inside my lib folder directly and one of those packages depends on dart:mirrors, which cannot be used during compilation. I may however be incorrect.

I thought maybe that I could exclude those libraries from compilation in some way (the builder class itself could be excluded from compilation, since I only need it for code generation), but I found no way of doing this.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In release builds flutter uses the AOT compiler to compile binary so dart mirrors are disabled in the Flutter builds as it can't be used with AOT.

For more information, you can read this faq: https://docs.flutter.dev/resources/faq#does-flutter-come-with-a-reflection--mirrors-system

It would be better to create a separate package or library for your code generation requirement.